# Recommendation for a stable text editor for react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Which package do you recommend for react-native text editor for ios and android? All the packages I looked at are not maintained.

Comment: I was using wix [editor](https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor). Actually, it's not perfect but is better than others.

Comment: I have issue with instalation react-native-webview-bridge, get error missing 'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found for ios